# How to use a Dexter pop-up for the user to allow or deny access to the files?

Tags: xml, android-external-storage

This is part of the code that I wrote in `getPermission`

When I run the program, no pop-up opens for the user to confirm or reject, and it automatically switches to rejection mode. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```kotlin
private fun getPermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(requireContext())
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
                override fun onPermissionGranted(response: PermissionGrantedResponse) {
                    initialRecView()
                }

                override fun onPermissionDenied(response: PermissionDeniedResponse) {
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permission: PermissionRequest?,
                    token: PermissionToken?
                ) {
                    token?.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).check()
```

This is also the manifest file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```